# Is there any way to slow down webserver in Visual Studio 9.X

Tags: visual-studio

We're developing locally and sometimes it would be nice to test under the slightly slower conditions that are experienced when on QA or production.  Is there any way to slightly throttle webserver.exe, under Visual Studio 9.x?

Comment: Are you looking to stress test or just intentionally decrease the performance of your local machine?

Comment: Intentionally looking to decrease the performance.

Answer (score 3):

i don't know if there is a feature for that. but what i'm doing when i need something similiar, is that i create virtual pcs with less ram and just 1 cpu.

you can give it a try. it's for free
http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx

cheers

Answer (score 1):

After quick thingking i may present you the following ideas that came to my mind:

1. Use a CPU slowdown utility, i have used thoses ages agoe and dunno if they still work on modern OS's
2. Use the TaskManager to set a low priority to the webserver process
3. Write a small programm that uses lots of IO and CPU to slow down your other processes

If nr 2 is working, it might be the best sollution because nr 1 & 3 will slow down your whole machine. Otherwise the VM approach suggested by nWorx is also a good idea.